# Dynamically import of options in camel routes

Tags: sql, apache-camel, smpp

I am trying to find a way to pass in "destAddr=" in smpp route below, a value that comes from the above sql query in order to import the senders number in the sms destination address but after much search, I can't find a way. How can I save the value I need from the query and then use it dynamically in the smpp option? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
<from uri="sql:{{sql.selectRunRecList}}" />
<to uri="bean:smppBean?method=smsConstruct" />
<to uri="sql:{{sql.markSms}}"/>
<to uri="bean:smppBean?method=smsPrintText" />  
<to uri="file:C:/workspace/SMPP/outbox" />   
<to uri="smpp://smppclient@localhost:2775?password=password&amp;destAddr=  " />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this FAQ how to use dynamic values when sending to an endpoint in Camel
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try and use it. I've got a question for you. Why does in "SpringOrderToCsvBeanTest.xml", this line works "<to uri="file://target/orders/received?fileName=report-${header.Date}.csv"/>" but when I try to do this "<to uri="smpp://smppclient@localhost:2775?password=password&amp;destAddr= ${header.body}" />", it doesn't?

Comment: Because the file component has special support for dynamic expressions in the fileName option. Read the documentation at: http://camel.apache.org/file2 , eg the table with the options. This is documented in the row for the fileName option.

Comment: Small details make a big difference! Is there a way to get the exchange object inside a bean without using a process?

Comment: Yep just use a bean. See the Camel docs about bean and bean binding, or check chapter 4 in the Camel in Action book for much more details

Comment: if I do this `<to uri="smpp://smppclient@localhost:2775?password=password&amp;destAddr=6944000001" />` I get from SUBMIT_SMS `dest_addr=6944000001` which is want I want to recreate dynamically. When I follow the Recipient List Pattern and do this `<recipientList><header>recipients</header></recipientList>` in the spring xml and `String destination = "smpp://smppclient@localhost:2775?password=password&amp;destAddr=" + msisdn;exchange.getIn().setHeader("recipients", destination);` I get the `dest_addr=1717` which is the default that means the dynamic injection doesn't work!

Comment: I found the solution to my above problem. It must be the "&" that separates the options in classic camel routes and not the "&amp;" that must be used when routing camel in spring.xml files. So the correct is `String destination = "smpp://smppclient@localhost:2775?password=password&destAddr=" + msisdn;`